# How to handle InvalidSignatureException exception and return custom error json response in laravel

Tags: laravel

I can't handle this exception. 
 - I used try-catch but this doesn't work. 
 - I used `$request->hasValidSignature()` but this doesn't work either.

What can I do about this? Please help me and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

In your `App\Exceptions\Handler@render()`, you could do something like this:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException) {
        if (request()->ajax() || request()->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['Error' => ['message' => 'Invalid Signature']], 500);
        } 

        return response()->view('errors.invalid-signature', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

If the exception being thrown is an instance of `\Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException`, it will be rendered using the view located at `resources/views/errors/invalid-signature` and with the HTTP code `500`.

The client can also receive a JSON response if it's expecting one. This is just an example. Feel free to modify it to your needs.

Edit: Based on your comment, you should try this instead:

```php
public function verify(Request $request)
{
    try {
        if ($request->route('id') == $request->user()->getKey() && $request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
            return response()->json([
                'code' => '200',
                'body' => __('responses.email-verified')
            ]);
        }
    } catch (\Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'Error' => ['message' => 'Invalid Signature nene']
        ]);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'Error' => ['message' => 'An Unknown error occured']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use this in controller method. But it doesn't work in controller method

Comment: If you could edit your answer to provide more context, it would be great :)

Comment: I want to use if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException){...} in controller not in handler class render method. because in controller I return different message.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really help. Could you post your current controller code?

Comment: Edited my answer to cater for your scenario.

Comment: thanks for all. but it doesn't work in my code. But I use your handler method. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9

When someone visits a signed URL that has expired, they will receive a generic error page for the 403 HTTP status code. However, you can customize this behavior by defining a custom "renderable" closure for the InvalidSignatureException exception in your exception handler. This closure should return an HTTP or Json response:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
    });

    $this->renderable(function (InvalidSignatureException $e) {
        if (request()->ajax() || request()->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json([], 403);
        }
        return response()->view('error.link-expired', [], 403);
    });
}
```